# Built Neutralino app cannot open localhost?

Tags: javascript, preact, neutralinojs

I have a very peculiar issue, I have a Neutralino app built with Preact that runs perfectly fine when run with `neu run`, however, once I build the project (with `enableServer` on or off), the built application will not load anything.

With `enableServer` on, it will complain that it cannot connect to localhost:
["This localhost page cannot be found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA2qq.png)

and with it off it gives me a completely white screen/DOM.

The GitHub repository is here: https://github.com/SpikeHD/XeniaLauncher

I suspect it may be the way I am building the project, but I find it weird that `neu run` works completely fine.

Below is my configuration:

```json
{
  "applicationId": "js.xenia_launcher.app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "defaultMode": "window",
  "port": 0,
  "documentRoot": "/build/",
  "url": "/",
  "enableServer": true,
  "enableNativeAPI": true,
  "tokenSecurity": "one-time",
  "logging": {
    "enabled": true,
    "writeToLogFile": true
  },
  "nativeAllowList": [
    "app.*",
    "os.*",
    "filesystem.*",
    "storage.*",
    "window.*",
    "debug.log"
  ],
  "modes": {
    "window": {
      "title": "XeniaLauncher",
      "width": 1000,
      "height": 800,
      "minWidth": 400,
      "minHeight": 200,
      "fullScreen": false,
      "alwaysOnTop": false,
      "icon": "/resources/icons/appIcon.png",
      "enableInspector": true,
      "borderless": false,
      "maximize": false,
      "hidden": false,
      "resizable": true,
      "exitProcessOnClose": true
    },
    "browser": {},
    "cloud": {
      "url": "/resources/#cloud",
      "nativeAllowList": [
        "app.*"
      ]
    },
    "chrome": {
      "width": 1000,
      "height": 800,
      "args": "--user-agent=\"Neutralinojs chrome mode\""
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "binaryName": "XeniaLauncher",
    "resourcesPath": "/resources/",
    "extensionsPath": "/extensions/",
    "clientLibrary": "/resources/js/neutralino.js",
    "binaryVersion": "4.4.0",
    "clientVersion": "3.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up: you're missing both `preact-cli` and `@neutralinojs/neu` from your `package.json` -- no one will be able to clone and run your app without separately installing them. If you've installed both globally, you should add a note in your ReadMe (and you really shouldn't be installing `preact-cli` globally, we cannot recommend against that enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! I ended up just setting up some scripts that will put all the built Preact code into the `resources` folder and re-setup my config to only use the resources folder, like the original Neutralino template. I am sure there could have been a more elegant way, but I am still just learning Neutralino *and* Preact so this works perfectly well enough for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `resourcesPath` needs to be set to the directory where your `index.html` is found. I have a `public` dir, and moved the icons over there, then set `resourcesPath` to `/public/` and I was able to `neu build --release` and run.